# How do I implement abstract class inside abstract class in the implementation class in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I have two classes which have structures look like the following code.

```
public class ClassOne {

  private Data data;

  public ClassOne(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public Data getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public static class Data {

    //code one

  }
}
```

---

```
public class ClassTwo {

  private Data data;

  public ClassTwo(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public Data getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public static class Data {

    //code two

  }
}
```

As you can see, those two classes have `Data` object which has different implementation. Could I move that `Data` object in the parent class and implement it in those two classes? It might looks like the following code.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

  Data data;

  public AbstractClass(Data data) {
    this.data = data;  
  }

  public Data getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public abstract class Data{}
}
```

---

```
public class ClassOne extends AbstractClass {

  public ClassOne(Data data) {
    super(data);
  }

  //Implementation from AbstractClass.Data
  public class Data {

    //code one

  }
}
```

---

```
public class ClassTwo extends AbstractClass {

  public ClassTwo(Data data) {
    super(data);
  }

  //Implementation from AbstractClass.Data
  public class Data {

    //code two

  }   
}
```

As I know, Java could only `extends` one class, so how do I implement the inner abstract class (`Data`)?

Comment: "*Could I move that `Data` object in the parent class and implement it in those two classes?*" Yes. "*how do I implement the inner abstract class (`Data`)?*" Depends on your design. Not sure what you want to get eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do, if I understand your problem correctly.

```
public class AbstractClass {

    protected AbstractData data;

    public AbstractClass(AbstractData data) {
        this.data=data;
    }

    public AbstractData getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public static interface AbstractData {
        public int getInt();
        public boolean getBool();
    }
}

public class ClassOne extends AbstractClass {

    public ClassOne(AbstractData data) {
        super(data);
    }

    @Override
    public AbstractData getData() {
        return data.getBool() ? data : null;
    }

    public static class DataOne implements AbstractData {

        @Override
        public int getInt() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getBool() {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public class DataTwo implements AbstractClass.AbstractData {

    @Override
    public int getInt() {
        return 42;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getBool() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here you can combine `AbstractClass` and `ClassOne` with both `DataOne` and `DataTwo` as you like.

But I don't see why `AbstractClass` should be abstract, so it isn't in this exmple. Of course, you can make it abstract and add abstract method as you like.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a static nested class then it becomes an integral part of the outer class. In your example two different classes with same name `Data` are part of outer classes `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo`. As the implementation of the two classes with same name `Data` is different there is no harm in keeping them the way it is. Anyhow you are not going to get any advantage the way you are planning to create an abstract class and then try to impose it on the other two classes. IMO it is perfectly fine the way it is.

Consider example of two classes `AVLTree` and `RedBlackTree` and both of these classes may need a class `Node` which will be different in nature. So it is perfectly fine and you do not need to refactor the code.